# How to check a field is increasing continuously or not in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a DB with about 500K document in MongoDB. My DB has a field `number` starting from 1 and increasing continuously. After I count total of the document, I realize some documents are missing (last `number` field is greater than total document, instead of equal). How can I check which document is missing? A document has the form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc"),
    "number" : 499661
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach. Consider you have these documents with missing numbers `1` and `4`:

```
{ number: 0 }
{ number: 2 }
{ number: 3 }
{ number: 5 }
{ number: 6 }
```

To find the two missing numbers, try this aggregation:

```
db.test.aggregate([ 
  { 
    $group: { 
        _id: null, 
        nums: { $push: "$number" } 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    $project: { 
        _id: 0,
        missing_numbers: { $setDifference: [ { $range: [ 0, 7 ] }, "$nums" ] } 
    } 
  },
])
```

The output: `{ "missing_numbers" : [ 1, 4 ] }`